# .NET cannot read data from requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

i'm struggling with simplest request handling in C# .NET, whenever i try to read something from request i usually get an Empty value.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class server_save : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string TXT_PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("files/saved.txt");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        string DATA = Request["data"];
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(TXT_PATH, true, Encoding.Default);
            writer.WriteLine(DATA);
            writer.Close();
            Response.Write(DATA);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Write(TXT_PATH);
        }

    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/nJYBm4mX

Comment: How you have defined `data` in your markup page? Can you show that?

Comment: what is Request["data"], a querystring parameter?

Comment: $.ajax({
                data: {data:"Buka"},
                method: "POST",
                url: "url string thingy"
            }).done(function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            });

Comment: I usually test such things on POSTman and the result is pretty much same thing.